# Java 8 UnaryOperator Chain with dynamic terminal operations within the chain

Tags: java, function, lambda, chain

I have a requirement to build workflows that differ based on the input type. Its like having a strategy pattern of workflows. I have to build a Result object as an output of the workflow. The result object type is same for all workflows.

So every workflow will take in and give out the same result object, however the steps in each workflow will be different. The workflow may terminate before the last step due to exception. In that case the result object will have the exception state and message.

For example:

If R is the result object then
every step will be implemented as R UnaryOperator(R r) function

I will then have a number of such steps that I want to combine (statically/compile time) as per my input types into a workflow such as

Workflow for Type A -> a1.andThen(a2).andThen(a3)
This can terminate at any step due to an exception or business logic

Workflow for Type B -> b1.andThen(a2).andThen(b3)
a2 is also a part of this workflow.

I will then select these workflows as a Strategy Pattern lambda.

Any ideas on the most efficient way to implements this?

Comment: if you have different implementations of `andThen` based on the type of `a1`/`b1`, then each intermediate result must differ in type as well.

Comment: I have implemented it as andThen chain that terminates on exception or completion. However the issue is that the chain must terminate intermediately if a business condition is met. Now andThen only terminates on exception.

Comment: Show us a simplified version of what you have (in code) and what the problem is and I'll look at it and try to answer your question.